# Does ActiveRecord make a new database connection per model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to understand how ActiveRecord connects to a database on a per model basis. So lets assume we have 2 models and one database. When you do a simple `Model.find` on both models does this create a new database connection for each model so it has its own defined connection or is there a single connection to the database that has been initialised that is shared across the 2 models. Does anyone know where it's doing this in the [code?](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord)

I am trying to understand how ActiveRecord achieves this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ActiveRecord` uses a connection pool. When you try to interact with the database, a connection is acquired from the pool, query is made and connection is returned to pool after the query. All this is handled by `ActiveRecord` in the background. 
You can adjust the number of connections in the pool in your database configuration

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html

You can test this easily. Execute a query in controller action that takes couple of minutes. Issue multiple requests to the action and you would be able to see out of connection errors

Comment: So a "connection pool" is actually individual connections to the database?

Comment: yes and they are kept open for a certain period based on the configuration

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for me. Also, if you were using MongoDB it has its own internal connection pool so ActiveRecord's connection pool isn't necessary here, right?

Comment: @Peter since establishing a new connection to a database takes significant time, and web systems are stateless, the framework would always need to keep connections open with the database. Although the database itself might provide connection pooling internally (Oracle can do the same), the primary purpose here is to keep connections between app and database constantly available.